# ARM64 ASIMD intrinsic to load uint8_t* into uint16x8(x3)?

Tags: c++, c, simd, arm64, neon

I'm looking for a way of loading elements from a 8-bit source array (`uint8_t*`) into AArch64 NEON / ASIMD register with data format `uint16x8_t` or even better `uint16x8x3_t`. So basically, each byte in the source array has to be loaded as a short into the register.

In a for-loop, I have to do the load in each iteration with a new batch of values.

I cannot find any ASIMD intrinsics to do this, but perhaps I am missing something. My current approach is to first load the elements as `uint8x8x3_t`, performing a widening left-shift (using `vmovl_u8`, so that the elements turn into `uint16x8_t`) but this seems very inefficient:

```c
uint8x8x3_t bgrChunk = vld3_u8(bgr);
uint16x8_t b = vmovl_u8(bgrChunk.val[0]);
uint16x8_t g = vmovl_u8(bgrChunk.val[1]);
uint16x8_t r = vmovl_u8(bgrChunk.val[2]);
bgr += 24; // Required for next iteration
```

I have also tried the following, but this performs even worse than the above;

```c
uint16_t bgrValues[] = { bgr++, bgr++, bgr++, ... repeat up to 24 elements ..., bgr++, bgr++ };
uint16x8x3_t bgrChunk = vld3q_u16(bgrValues);
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this, or am I missing some intrinsic that will make this easier for me?

**Edit; Extended example of what I want**

Lets say I have an array `uint8_t*` with values { 5, 33, 102, 153... }

Is there a way that I can directly load each 8-bit **individual** element into a register as a 16-bit value so that that register will  contain the **16-bit** values { 5, 33, 102, 153... }?

```c
void foo(uint8_t* bgr, uint16_t width, uint16_t height) {
  for (uint16_t y = 0; y < height; y++) {
    for (uint16_t x = 0; x < width; x += 8) {
      // I want to load 8-bit values as 16-bit values here. Is there a more efficient way to do this than the code below?
      uint8x8x3_t bgrChunk = vld3_u8(bgr);
      uint16x8_t b = vmovl_u8(bgrChunk.val[0]);
      uint16x8_t g = vmovl_u8(bgrChunk.val[1]);
      uint16x8_t r = vmovl_u8(bgrChunk.val[2]);
      bgr += 24;
      // ... Some operations working on the loaded data
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: For starters, I'd post your non-neon C code as a guide. You should have this anyway so you can validate whatever SIMD code you come up with. It isn't so much just loading the values, but what you want to do with them that dictates which SIMD instructions can be used. Also, instead of `bgr` being a `uint8_t *`, why isn't it a `uint8x8x3_t *`? As I'm familiar with x86 simd but not neon, I assume that's something like `typedef struct bgr { uint8_t r,g,b; } __attribute__((packed)) uint8x8x3_t;` or `typedef struct bgr { uint8_t val[3]; } __attribute__((packed)) uint8x8x3_t;`

Comment: @CraigEstey I have updated my question with a more extensive example of what I am looking for.

`bgr` is the `uint8_t*` that I want to load where each 8-bit value is loaded as a 16-bit value while retaining it's original value; so a byte with for example value '129' should be loaded into a uint16x8_t vector but still having the value '129'.

Is this more clear?

Comment: Somewhat, but it still just gets the rgb values into individual scalars. For example, do you want to get the luma value from the rgb? Convert the rgb to YCbCr, YUV422, YUV420, etc? Apply a 3x3 convolution kernel to sharpen/blur? Split the combined rgb into three planar arrays? Do a multitap FIR filter? And so on ... In x86, there are simd unpack instructions that can shuffle bytes (e.g. `punpcklbw` et. al. which is convoluted) but will expand bytes to 16 bits words (e.g. bytes: `01020304` --> words: `0001,0002,0003,0004`)

Comment: From the tags and mention of NEON, you're writing 32-bit code, right?  Anyway, I think Craig's point is that you might be able to avoid just unpacking if you can use some kind of widening operation as the first step of whatever you're doing next with the data.  It's still a valid question regardless, it just might be an X-Y problem if your use-case can avoid unpacking each of the u8 elements to u16.  Or if they don't need to be in that order, odd/even masking with AND might be possible.

Comment: Also, assuming 128 bit SIMD registers. As bytes from `rgbrgbrgbrgbrgb` do you want interleaved 16 bit: `0r0g0b...0r0g0b` or three separate simd registers: `0r0r0r0r`, `0g0g0g0g`, and `0b0b0b0b` (e.g.)?

Comment: @CraigEstey I want to have three separate SIMD registers `rrrrrrrr` `ggggggg` `bbbbbbbb`.

The end goal is to do color space conversions (in this case BGR888 to YUV420). For learning purposes I want to see if I can implement an efficient algorithm to do so.

I've already got working code, just looking to optimize the loading-part a bit more. 

--  i'm just wondering if there is an efficient way to load 8-bit values as 16-bit values in NEON.

Comment: @PeterCordes I'm working on a 64-bit ARM machine. Register size is 128-bits indeed.

Comment: Ok, I fixed the tags for you.  There isn't a separate tag for AArch64's ASIMD as opposed to 32-bit ARM NEON, because most ASIMD instructions are equivalent to their NEON counterparts, although the partial register aliasing is different (in AArch32, a 128-bit `q` register has two 64-bit `d` halves.  In AArch64, the high 64 bits don't have separate names, but there are instructions like `zip2` that read the high half).

Comment: Okay, here's a model for using integer math to get YCbCr: https://sistenix.com/rgb2ycbcr.html You should be able to apply this and get 8 pixels per loop using operations that treat the registers as 8 independent 16 bit words (e.g. x86 `PADDUSW` et. al.)

Comment: @CraigEstey I appreciate the resource, but it is not an answer to the question I am asking :-) 

Aside from my use-case/context, there may be other contexts in which people bump into similar questions as me (loading 8-bit values as 16-bit values).

Comment: See: https://developer.arm.com/documentation/den0018/a/NEON-Instruction-Set-Architecture/Packing-and-unpacking-data?lang=en and https://arm-software.github.io/acle/neon_intrinsics/advsimd.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's an orthogonal instruction set for load/stores, so for widening loads you'll need to load 8-bit values into registers, and then widen to 16-bits as a second operation.

Depending what you do next, it is often possible for this second operation to be a useful arithmetic operation not just a move. For example, `vmull_s8()`, `vaddl_s8()`, `vsubl_s8()` all return a 16-bit result. There are similar narrowing equivalents if you want to go the other way.

Comment: Awesome answer and great examples there on the instructions that help in widening the values, thank you.

So my initial approach (first loading then widening) was not far off; I'll still have to dive into if for my specific use-case I can combine the widening with a useful operation.